# How can I access/administer IIS running on XP from other computers?

Tags: iis-6, remote-desktop, iis

I have a question regarding IIS for XP. I used to install and use IIS 5.1 on my XP pro and install and use IIS 6.0 on XP pro 64bit edtion for a little while.
I read that I can access and administer IIS on XP from remote computers by u**sing IIS manager.**

But when I was using IIS I didn't know that remote computers can administer my IIS on XP... and it worries me a little. Does it mean that computers on the same LAN network or even computers on outside of my LAN network(on the internet) can administer my IIS on my XP via IIS manager remotely without setting up or anything??

I looked for everywhere for the information and they all say you can do that, but it doesn't say any password protection or security issue for that.... and I was wondering if computers other than my local XP which running IIS on can administer access remotely to my IIS if they know my IP address? my XP computers were on home network and behind a router.

Also If I install I**IS 5.1** on xp, remote desktop / remote desktop web connection are also enabled by default?

If anybody reply and explain to me I would really really appreciate it!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need any software installed - just right click on your "My Computer" icon and choose "manage".  When the management console opens, right click on the computer name and choose "connect to another computer".  This will let you enter the name of your web server, and after connecting will show IIS Manager in the tree structure on the left.

Thankfully, there is authentication involved here -- it's just that normally you don't see it because it uses your active directory domain credentials.  Also, remote desktop is *not* enabled by default on Windows XP, though it is common for administrators to turn it on by default on all workstations via group policy so that they can connect when they need to.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  I was using IIS on my xp on homenetwork and it was not a domain environment like a office.  If my iis xp computer is not on a domain environment and the xp user account doesn't have password, remote computers outside of my LAN network can access to my iis without password?    Also I read somewhere that if you install IIS 5.1 it also installs remote desktop web connection component by default. Is it true??  sorry for asking many thing..if you could reply I would really appreciate it.

Comment: They cannot access IIS manager from outside the LAN - you won't have the right ports forwarded.  It does install a remote component -- look at http://yourwebserver/tsweb  -- that's pretty easy to disable in IIS, though.

Comment: Hello Joel.  Thank you for your reply and help! one thing I would like to make sure(sorry for asking over and over again), by installing IIS on XP will NOT turn on/enable Remote Desktop on that computer automatically?

Comment: No, it won't enable remote desktop.

Answer (score 1):

IIS Manager uses [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication), meaning that it will attempt to authenticate you with you logged in users details first. If that does not succeed you may get a details prompt box (username/password).

This means that you must have had the same username/password on both machines with allowed you seamless authentication.

I would post another relevant link but I am not allowed to...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Does it mean if i don't have password for my user account on my xp and if the remote computers have the same user account name as my xp, they can administer my iis without password even if they are outside of my LAN network?  Also If I install IIS 5.1, is remote desktop web access option also installed and enabled automatically?  I would appreciate it if you can reply again.